# Continue javascript execution when errors occurs

Tags: javascript, errors, wp-enqueue-script

I use the WP native function wp_enqueue_script() for all my JavaScripts loading both in WP front and back-end so it can handle duplicated calls to the same script and so on.

One of the issues is that others programmers don't use this function and load their scripts directly from their code, which causes jQuery or jQuery-UI being loaded twice, leading to a bunch of errors.

The other issue is that code not owned by my triggers an error and stops the execution of the JavaScript beyond this point.

**EDIT:**

In short:

1. A javascript error occurs in code not owned by me.
2. My code don't executes due to that f*%@ error.
3. I want that my code bypass that error and still executes.

There is a way to handle these issues?

Comment: Use jQuery and jQuery ui in no conflict mode http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Your question is rather broad. Perhaps you could narrow it down to a single WordPress-specific issue?

Comment: @all: Thanks for taking time to answer, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I'm already using jQuery in the noConflict mode and the issue still remains.

Comment: @bungeshea: Sorry, but I can't narrow it more than that. The issue is: 1- a javascript error occurs in code not owned by me. 2- my code don't executes due to that f*%@ error. 3- I want that my code bypass that error and still executes.

Comment: JavaScript execution being halted due to an error is not unique to WordPress, this question is off-topic for this site.